# What is the shell: part of a command that you put into run called?

Tags: windows-10

There are all of these `shell:*` ([commands](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3109-shell-commands-list-windows-10-a.html)?) available and they aren't in my path, but `shell:` seems almost like a parent folder, or a library or something, but I don't know what to call it.  What is it called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case `shell:` probably works like a URL scheme, much like `http:` or `ftp:`.

The Windows Explorer shell supports directly starting URLs (there are URL scheme associations in the Registry right next to file extension associations), and Windows has for a very long time used various custom URL schemes for internal purposes, from *ms-its:* for HTML Help to *ms-settings:* which starts an UWP app. So *shell:* is a built-in URL scheme that is handled by Explorer itself.

Answer (score 3):

Those are specially named containers that Explorer understands.  Think of them like aliases for the actual directory path.  I believe the official term is [Shell Namespace Folders](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/namespace-intro).

Per @KeithMiller's comment:
Although you mention the Run dialog, the Shell command also works from the Explorer Adddress Bar. So while `:` begins a drive path and `\\` signals a UNC path, Shell tells Explorer that what follows is the ID of a known Namespace Folder/Item.

Comment: Okay so it's a `namespace` then?